# Would bulk copy/insert be affected if a table exceeds millions of records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Last year, I wrote a powershell script that has a DMV query that pulls results into a variable and then inserts those results using bulk copy into another table i had created to save this data then export it to a csv file. We use AutoSys for scheduling jobs so in this case, we set 5 minutes increments for this script to run everytime to stay up to date with usage data. so every minute that table is getting updated with about 5-10 records technically. 
the next day, we exported a csv file with all data in that table for that prior day, then truncated the table.

we received a requirement to retain usage information for up to 2 years (long story). 
so ***we altered the truncate statement in the script to delete records only if they are older than 2 years.*** we tested it of course and it worked fine in Dev/Test (with a shorter time span)

ever since, the table now has over 5 million records after 2 months, and we started seeing the Autosys job failing/restarting often recently.

So the question is, ***is it possible that because the table is now growing fast, with millions of records, that this is is causing a performance issue by the bulk copy query***? does the query "get tired" maybe because there is a bunch of transactions at once?

as far as i know, a table can have millions of records and there wouldnt be an issues with continous inserts nonstop. but maybe bulk copy is different from a regular insert? im thinking of increasing the job scheduling from 5 mins to 10 mins, but im afraid we might lose some usage data here between that extra gap. and it might not even be a solution to the issue...

Comment: If you are keeping historical data why are you deleting and recopying it over and over and over? Why not track when you last ran the export process and then adjust your queries to only get the data that changed since the last run? Copying 2 million + rows every day sounds like an exercise in futility when the data hasn't changed.

Comment: @SeanLange oh i think there is a misunderstanding. we dont copy the data over and over, because the DMV query only pulls data from the current time it is queried. whats happening is the bulk copy is inserting this NEW data from the DMV query everytime it runs, so its just appending to the table, not duplicating the same data. so every record is distinct, thats because the usage execution times are different every second. its just that instead of truncating the table the following day after exporting to a csv file, we are now only truncating records older than 2 years.

Comment: is it the bulk insert that takes too long or every time the script runs it tries to delete rows which are older than 2 years (if yes, then isn't this excessive? a deletion once per day would suffice)

Comment: @lptr my bad, i should have specified that i have another script that does the export to a csv file, separate from the script that has the DMV query/bulk copy. so that second script that exports to csv does the truncation, which is only once the next day when the export is completed (and thats only if data is older than 2 years. since we just implemented this process, no records are older than 2 years so nothing has been truncated as expected. i assume the table will continue growing up to 120 million rows after almost 2 years from now.)